# How to get the data from JS function to controller class

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

How to get company name in controller class, when i am printing String cname = req.getParameter("companyName"), it is showing undefined.

Adding snapshots for reference.

[image: JS]

**Edit Company Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editCompany", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editCompany(ModelAndView model, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {

        String cname = req.getParameter("companyName");
        System.out.println(cname);

        //int companyId = companyDAO.GetCompanyId(req.getParameter("companyName"));
        Company company = companyDAO.getInfo(req.getParameter("companyName")) ;
        model.addObject("company", company);
        model = getDropdownList(model); 
        model.setViewName("editCompany");
        return model;
    }
```

**JS**

```
$("#EditBtn").click(function(e) {
      var companyName=$("#table tr.trActive td:first").html();
      $
    .ajax({
      type : "GET",
      url : "editCompany?companyName="+companyName,
      data : JSON.stringify(companyName),
      contentType: "text/plain",
      success : function(data) {

        alert('sucess');
      //viewCompanyViaAjax();
      },
      error : function() {
        alert('Error occured');
      }



});
```

[Updated snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PnPE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**In JS**
You don't need data in both variants, because it is Get, not Post method.

**First variant:**
*In JS*

```
url : "editCompany/"+companyName
```

*Edit Company Controller*

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editCompany/{companyName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editCompany(@PathVariable String companyName, ModelAndView model, HttpServletResponse res) {
System.out.println(companyName);
...
```

**Second Variant**
*In JS*

```
url : "editCompany?companyName="+companyName
```

*Edit Company Controller*

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editCompany", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editCompany(@RequestParam("companyName") String companyName, ModelAndView model, HttpServletResponse res) {
System.out.println(companyName);
...
```